# How can I switch the working branch (Git) in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm working in Android Studio with 3 branches as follow:

> master -> Transactions -> Sub

Now the default branch I am developing is Sub, but now I want to return to the Branch Transactions and later I want to return in Sub again.

I don't want merge the branches now

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that you don't have uncommitted changes. When done you can switch the braches as you like. If you have unstaged changes you can stash them to ignore the changes for now without discarding them. I have no idea how to stash it within Android Studio, but can switch the branches in the lower right of Android Studio check this screenshot:

[image: branches screenshot]

Comment: Thanks, it worked!! The only difference to me was in Android Studio I have the option Local Branch -> Checkout

Comment: This option is not in my toolbar ? How to enable it ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a Git user, but I think you can use the Studios' Git button located in the bottom left corner:

[image]

Comment: You helped me a lot. The only difference in Android Studio, I had to click in Local Branch -> Checkout. Thanks!